# How to perform Kmeans from scratch for Categorical Data?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I wish to perform Kmeans on Continent Dataset without using SKlearn. I am trying with only one feature i.e. Continent Name. The column has categorical data, so I performed some manipulation for the data.

**Dataset**

| name | Longitude | Latitude | continent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aruba | -69.982677 | 12.520880 | North America |
| Afghanistan | 66.004734 | 33.835231 | Asia |
| Angola | 17.537368 | -12.293361 | Africa |
| Anguilla | -63.064989 | 18.223959 | North America |
| Albania | 20.049834 | 41.142450 | Europe |

**Code**

```
#imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Converting Categorical Data
dataframe['continent'] = dataframe.loc[:, 'continent'].map({'North America':0,'Europe':1,'Asia':2,'Africa':3,'South America':4, 'Oceania':5,'Seven seas (open ocean)':6, 'Antarctica':7})
dataframe.head()

#getting feature vector
X = dataframe.iloc[:, 3:4]

np.random.seed(42)


def euclidean_distance(x1, x2):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((x1 - x2) ** 2))


class KMeans:
    def __init__(self, K=5, max_iters=100, plot_steps=False):
        self.K = K
        self.max_iters = max_iters
        self.plot_steps = plot_steps

        # list of sample indices for each cluster
        self.clusters = [[] for _ in range(self.K)]
        # the centers (mean feature vector) for each cluster
        self.centroids = []

    def predict(self, X):
        self.X = X
        self.n_samples, self.n_features = X.shape

        # initialize
        random_sample_idxs = np.random.choice(self.n_samples, self.K, replace=False)
        self.centroids = [self.X[idx] for idx in random_sample_idxs]

        # Optimize clusters
        for _ in range(self.max_iters):
            # Assign samples to closest centroids (create clusters)
            self.clusters = self._create_clusters(self.centroids)

            if self.plot_steps:
                self.plot()

            # Calculate new centroids from the clusters
            centroids_old = self.centroids
            self.centroids = self._get_centroids(self.clusters)

            # check if clusters have changed
            if self._is_converged(centroids_old, self.centroids):
                break

            if self.plot_steps:
                self.plot()

        # Classify samples as the index of their clusters
        return self._get_cluster_labels(self.clusters)

    def _get_cluster_labels(self, clusters):
        # each sample will get the label of the cluster it was assigned to
        labels = np.empty(self.n_samples)

        for cluster_idx, cluster in enumerate(clusters):
            for sample_index in cluster:
                labels[sample_index] = cluster_idx
        return labels

    def _create_clusters(self, centroids):
        # Assign the samples to the closest centroids to create clusters
        clusters = [[] for _ in range(self.K)]
        for idx, sample in enumerate(self.X):
            centroid_idx = self._closest_centroid(sample, centroids)
            clusters[centroid_idx].append(idx)
        return clusters

    def _closest_centroid(self, sample, centroids):
        # distance of the current sample to each centroid
        distances = [euclidean_distance(sample, point) for point in centroids]
        closest_index = np.argmin(distances)
        return closest_index

    def _get_centroids(self, clusters):
        # assign mean value of clusters to centroids
        centroids = np.zeros((self.K, self.n_features))
        for cluster_idx, cluster in enumerate(clusters):
            cluster_mean = np.mean(self.X[cluster], axis=0)
            centroids[cluster_idx] = cluster_mean
        return centroids

    def _is_converged(self, centroids_old, centroids):
        # distances between each old and new centroids, fol all centroids
        distances = [
            euclidean_distance(centroids_old[i], centroids[i]) for i in range(self.K)
        ]
        return sum(distances) == 0

    def plot(self):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

        for i, index in enumerate(self.clusters):
            point = self.X[index].T
            ax.scatter(*point)

        for point in self.centroids:
            ax.scatter(*point, marker="x", color="black", linewidth=2)

        plt.show()


# Testing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

    X, y = make_blobs(
        centers=3, n_samples=500, n_features=2, shuffle=True, random_state=40
    )
    print(X.shape)

    clusters = len(np.unique(y))
    print(clusters)

    k = KMeans(K=clusters, max_iters=150, plot_steps=True)
    y_pred = k.predict(X)

    k.plot()
```

In the above code, how can I replace the make_blobs dataset generation part, so that it uses Continent dataset for clustering, based on single feature vector X?

Comment: Reconsider if K-Means is the right way to go - check Hierarchical clustering on https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#

Comment: You want to use **only** the continent for clustering? So, countries on the same continent should be grouped together, and countries on different continents should be grouped separately? If so, then you don't need any fancy algorithm. Just group by continent.